# How do I find the average of the whole class?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
struct Students
{
    char name[30];
    char first_name[30];
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int n3;
}student list[10];

    int n;
void reading_student_list()
{
    int i;
    ifstream f("in.txt");
    f>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        f>>student_list[i].name;
        f>>student_list[i].first_name;
        f>>student_list[i].n1;
        f>>student_list[i].n2;
        f>>student_list[i].n3;
    }
    f.close();
}
void showing_student_list()
{
    int i;
    ofstream g("out.txt");
    g<<"\n Student list: ";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        g<<"\n\n";
        g<<student_list[i].name<<" ";
        g<<student_list[i].first_name<<" ";
        g<<student_list[i].n1<<" ";
        g<<student_list[i].n2<<" ";
        g<<student_list[i].n3<<" ";
        g<<endl<<"Average: "<<float(student_list[i].n1+student_list[i].n2+student_list[i].n3)/3;
    }
    cout<<"\n Open file out.txt";
    g.close();
}
    int main()
    {
        reading_student_list();
        showing_student_list();
    }
```

I did the average for the grades per student, but I can't figure out how to find the average for the whole class.

After doing the average for the whole class, I can figure out the students that have their average below average of the class and the highest average of the class.

Comment: add up all the student averages and divide by `n`?

Comment: How can i add all the students averages?
Thats what i don't get .

Comment: Write a loop going through the students one at a time and adding up the grades. You've already written a loop to print each student, it's no different.

Comment: @john Could u show me a example of this?

Comment: One reason not to use names like `n1` `n2` and `n3` is that no-one but you can tell what they mean. I don't which of your variables represents the student grades.

Comment: Have you not done a "calculate the sum of the elements in an array" exercise? That, or something similar, is often in the introduction to arrays.

Comment: n1= grade 1, n2= grade 2, n3= grade 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you would add up all the `n1` values (whatever that means).

```
int total = 0;               // start the total at zero
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  // for each student
    total += list[i].n1;     // add list[i].n1 to total
```

Hopefully you can adapt that to suit your particular requirements.

Comment: So i should do this for n2 and n3 too? Should i do it in a void function?

Comment: I really can't answer either of those questions, you know what you've been asked to do better than me. And the second question is about programming style, and there are no right or wrong answers to those kind of questions. Do whatever makes most sense to you.